# optimizing a slow query to find hole in sequence

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table which looks like this:

```
id | serial_number_basic | product_id
-------------------------------------
```

The serial_number_basic is a running number which counts up every time a new number is needed. In the past it was possible to leave whole ranges of this number empty and the next number was `MAX() + 1`.

Due to changes in the requirements, the empty holes should be filled now. The serial_number_basic depends of course on the product_id. Each product has its own sequence of serial_number_basics. The problem is to find the holes.

This query does find the holes depending on each [productid], but unfortunately it is way too slow:

```
SELECT (
MIN( serial_number_basic ) + 1 
) as next_available_box
FROM (
SELECT DISTINCT t0.serial_number_basic, t1.serial_number_basic AS number_plus_one
FROM (SELECT * FROM conv WHERE product_id = [productid]) AS t0
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT * FROM conv WHERE product_id = [productid]) AS t1
ON t0.serial_number_basic + 1 = t1.serial_number_basic
) AS sub
WHERE number_plus_one IS NULL;
```

Comment: What happens when the gap fills up>

Comment: Please note that unless you are ocasionally sanitizing this value, it may still be possible for gaps to creep back into the sequence; This type of issue is usually related to rolling back transactions, so this might not be a large issue.

Comment: @Exceptiondev: Do you have an index on `(product_id, serial_number_basic)` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without any aggregates, no order-by, just a simple outer join, try:

```
SELECT MIN(c1.serial_number_basic) + 1
FROM conv c1
LEFT JOIN conv c2 
    ON c2.serial_number_basic = c1.serial_number_basic+1
    AND c2.product_id = c1.product_id
WHERE c1.product_id = 2
    AND c2.id IS null
```

Comment: Isn't min() an aggregate function? And don't min() needs ordering to find the minimum value?

Comment: MIN can be derived with just an index seek.

Answer (score 1):

You can cut out all the sub-queries by using `GROUP BY`. Then the `MIN` in your SELECT clause will cover just the one product_id for each row:

```
SELECT
  MIN(c.serial_number_basic) + 1 AS next_available_box,
  c.product_id
FROM conv c
LEFT JOIN conv AS c1 
  ON (c1.product_id = c.product_id AND c1.serial_number_basic - 1 = c.serial_number_basic)
WHERE c1.serial_number_basic IS NULL
GROUP BY c.product_id
ORDER BY c.product_id ASC;
```

Returns:

```
+--------------------+------------+
| next_available_box | product_id |
+--------------------+------------+
|                  4 |          1 |
|                  2 |          2 |
+--------------------+------------+
```

from a dataset of:

```
+---------------------+------------+
| serial_number_basic | product_id |
+---------------------+------------+
|                   1 |          1 |
|                   2 |          1 |
|                   3 |          1 |
|                   5 |          1 |
|                   6 |          1 |
|                   1 |          2 |
|                   3 |          2 |
|                   8 |          2 |
|                   9 |          2 |
+---------------------+------------+
```

Just one caveat - you will only get the first gap, you will have to verify another way if your serial_number_basic doesn't start at the lowest possible number for each product.

Comment: Thank you, this is 2 time faster already! Unfortunately it still takes up to 20 sec. in a dataset of 7000 convs with 12 products.

Answer (score 0):

Table:

```
create table conv (id int, serial_number_basic int, product_id int);
insert into conv (id, serial_number_basic, product_id) values
(1,1,1),
(2,2,1),
(3,3,1),
(4,5,1),
(5,6,1),
(6,1,2),
(7,3,2),
(8,8,2),
(9,9,2),
(10,2,3)
;
```

Query:

```
set @snb := 1;
set @pid := -1;
select sw.product_id, min(sw.serial_number_basic) as lowest_gap
from (
    select
        case 
            when @pid != ss.product_id 
            then @snb := 1 
            else @snb := @snb + 1 
            end as serial_number_basic,
        @pid := ss.product_id as product_id
    from (
        select serial_number_basic, product_id
        from conv
        order by product_id, serial_number_basic
    ) ss
) sw
left outer join conv
on  sw.product_id = conv.product_id 
    and 
    sw.serial_number_basic = conv.serial_number_basic
where conv.product_id is null
group by sw.product_id
order by sw.product_id
;
```

Result:

```
+------------+------------+
| product_id | lowest_gap |
+------------+------------+
|          1 |          4 |
|          2 |          2 |
|          3 |          1 |
+------------+------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

EDIT:

Probably much faster:

```
set @snb := 1;
set @pid := -1;
select product_id, min(gap) as lowest_gap
from (
    select
        case 
            when @pid != product_id 
            then @snb := 1 
            else @snb := @snb + 1 
            end,
         case
            when @snb != serial_number_basic
            then @snb else null
            end as gap,
        @pid := ss.product_id as product_id
    from (
        select serial_number_basic, product_id
        from conv
        order by product_id, serial_number_basic
    ) ss
) sw
where gap is not null
group by product_id
order by product_id
;
```

Comment: Added a probably much faster version

Answer (score 0):

First, create a table with all integers in range `1` to `10^5` :

```
CREATE TABLE digit
  ( d INT );

INSERT INTO digit               --- without zero
  VALUES
    (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),
    (6),(7),(8),(9) ;

CREATE TABLE number
  ( n INT PRIMARY KEY );

INSERT INTO number
  VALUES
    (1) ;    

INSERT INTO number                          --- run this 5 times 
  SELECT n + (SELECT MAX(n) FROM number)*d
  FROM number
    CROSS JOIN digit ;
```

Now, for a certain product, we can run this:

```
SELECT
    @product_id
  , MIN(number.n) AS next_available_serial
FROM 
    number
  LEFT JOIN conv AS c
    ON c.serial_number_basic = number.n
    AND c.product_id = @product_id
WHERE c.serial_number_basic IS NULL
```

For all products this would do (but **I have no idea if the `CROSS JOIN` will be fast or slow as hell...**):

```
SELECT
    p.product_id
  , MIN(number.n) AS next_available_serial
FROM 
    ( SELECT DISTINCT
          product_id
      FROM conv
    ) AS p
  CROSS JOIN number
  LEFT JOIN conv AS c
    ON c.serial_number_basic = number.n
    AND c.product_id = p.product_id
WHERE c.serial_number_basic IS NULL
GROUP BY p.product_id
```